# vfork VS fork in MPI mutiple thread

Tags: c, mpi

My program is very very large. So, I can't list it here. My program uses openMPI & mutiple_thread.

The problem has been solved. (using vfork() instead of fork()) But I don't know why it works. So, could anyone give me an explaination about it?

The problem is caused by free(). 
There are some segments of code in my program. All these segments are in threads which is created by pthread_create. The logic of these segments are like:

```
{
    *p = malloc();
    fun(p);
    free(p);
}
```

All errors are at free(). It report a segment fault error. I ran the program more than 100 times. I found that there is always a fork() being called before each corruption at free.

The logic of fork segment is like(in thread):

```
{
    MPI_program_code...
    if(!fork())
    {
        execv(exe_file,arg);
    }
    MPI_program_code...
}
```

(Note that, in exe_file no MPI_function is used.)

When I use vfork() instead of fork(), there is no problem at all. But I don't know why it works.

So, could anyone explain why it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the Open MPI FAQ topic on [forking child processes](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning#fork-warning) very useful. Also an explanation on why using `fork()` with InfiniBand is dangerous can be found [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=openfabrics#ofa-fork).

`vfork(2)` differs from `fork(2)` in that it is specifically designed to be as lightweight as possible and is only meant to be used together with an **immediately** following `execve(2)` (or any of its wrappers from the C library) or `_exit(2)` call. The reason for that is that `vfork(2)` creates a child process that shares all memory with the parent instead of having it copy-on-write mapped, i.e. the new child is more like a thread than like a full-blown process. Since the child also uses the stack of the original thread, the parent is blocked until the child has either execve'd another executable or exited.

Open MPI registers a `fork()` handler using `pthread_atfork()`. The handler is not called when `vfork()` is used on modern Linux systems, therefore no actions are taken by the parent process upon forking.

Comment: Thanks! I love your anwsers. You solved my problem twice! I really appreciate. This program will be run in Tianhe 2 after a few days. I really worried if it can run at 300,000 cores scale. Haha. I will try my best to make it.

Comment: Forking child processes from MPI ranks is generally a very bad and non-portable thing to do. I really hope that you have a very good reason for that.

Comment: I really do not want to use fork in MPI. But the main purpose of my program is to manage computation resource in a super computing environment and allocate jobs in these computation nodes. So, I need to fork work jobs in MPI program. Is there some other ways to start a process in MPI program?

Comment: I see, using system-specific interfaces should then be acceptable in that case. MPI provides only `MPI_Comm_spawn` as a mean to start additional processes in the form of child MPI jobs.